# How do I setup Grafana on an EC2 instance using IAM Auth for an RDS mysql instance?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-iam, grafana

I have an ELK stack with grafana installed on EC2 instances. I've created a mysql database in RDS, created a grafana database and a grafana user with the appropriate permissions. That user is able to be accessed via mysql utilizing an appropriately setup IAM role.

However, when I try to start the Grafana service using that database I get the following error in the logs:

```
"Fail to initialize orm engine" logger=sqlstore error="Sqlstore::Migration 
failed err: Error 1045: Access denied for user 'grafana'@'SERVERIP' (using 
password: YES)\n"
```

My grafana.ini database section looks like:

```
[database]
host = aurora-cluster-ClusterName.cluster-
RandomAWSSuppliedChars.Region.rds.amazonaws.com:3306
type = mysql
name = grafanaDbName
user = grafanaUserName
password = `aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname aurora-cluster-
  ClusterName.cluster-RandomAWSSuppliedChars.Region.rds.amazonaws.com --
  username grafanaUserName --port 3306 --region
  Region`
```

I've tried supplying no password as well, but I'm pretty sure I need the generated auth token to be supplied. I also tried generating an auth token and pasting it in manually during the 15 minute window while it's good for testing purposes and I got the same Access denied error.

Is IAM Authentication supported? If so, how do I supply the required Auth token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file needs several specific settings in order to connect. RDS requires *both* an ssl certificate, and an IAM token. The token is a long generated string which is best set to an environment variable and then passed in. The certificate must be [downloaded](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html) and made accessible.

```
[database]
host = ClusterUri:3306
type = mysql
name = grafanaDatabaseName
user = grafanaUserName
password = AwsSuppliedToken
ssl_mode=true
ca_cert_path=/CertificatePath/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
server_cert_name=ClusterName.cluster-RandomAwsSuppliedCharacters.AwsRegion.rds.amazonaws.com
```

Comment: Hey @necoras. The IAM token expires every 15 mins. How did you solve updating the IAM token for grafana every 15 min?

Comment: Hey, did you manage to get grafana working with IAM? How did you manage to refresh the password every 15 mins?

Comment: I honestly don't recall. It's been 4 years and this was a POC project.